# unlist vectors and create a data frame from existing data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a new data frame from an existing data frame which is of the following format. 
Data frame(df) is of the form

```
   A           B                                    C
   london   c("Kompast", "Kirklan", "Com")    c("April 1989- June 1990", "July 1990-May 2000", "May 2000-July 2012")
   sydney   c("kkj", "krr")                   c("April 1990-May 2000", "May 2000-March 2012")
   newyork  Coml                              c("April 1990- May 2013", "2 years")
   chicago   NULL                              NULL
```

I need to unlist the data frame and obtain them as rows as follows:

```
A        B             C
london  Kompast April 1989- June 1990
london  Kirklan July 1990-May 2000
london  Com     May 2000-July 2012
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @akrun, if I remember correctly, that function isn't vectorized. Possible reimplementation here: https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/065c8b82a24fb369c971 (working version in the comment at the gist).

Comment: How did you get to this point?  I think it would be best to go back and figure out why you have unevaluated calls in the columns, and fix it.

Comment: Do you mean `list("Kompast", "Kirklan", "Com")` instead of `c("Kompast", "Kirklan", "Com")` for the row?

Comment: The vectors B, C are lists. The data frame lists them as c("Kompast", "Kirklan", "Com"). So for each location there will be multiple B's and C's

Comment: It would be best to share a `dput` of a few lines of your data.

Comment: @user3570187, If they are list columns, try the functions at the gist I've linked to above. You would need both `flatten` and the `flattenLong` that is posted as a comment to the gist.

Comment: I have added few rows from the dataset. I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you can possibly look into my `flatten` and `flattenLong` functions that are presently at [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/065c8b82a24fb369c971) (and recreated below).

First, here is some sample data. `df_1` has a balanced number of items in each list in columns "B" and "C", along with one item that is `NULL`. On the other hand, `df_2` has an unbalanced number of items in each of the list columns, with `NULL`s interspersed.

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  A = c("london", "sydney", "new york", "chicago"),
  B = I(list(letters[1:3], letters[4:5], letters[6], NULL)),
  C = I(list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[4:5], LETTERS[6], NULL))
)
df_1
#          A       B       C
# 1   london a, b, c A, B, C
# 2   sydney    d, e    D, E
# 3 new york       f       F
# 4  chicago                

df_2 <- data.frame(
  A = c("london", "sydney", "new york", "chicago"),
  B = I(list(letters[1:3], letters[4:5], letters[6], NULL)),
  C = I(list(LETTERS[1:2], NULL, LETTERS[3:5], LETTERS[6:7]))
)
df_2
#          A       B       C
# 1   london a, b, c    A, B
# 2   sydney    d, e        
# 3 new york       f C, D, E
# 4  chicago            F, G
```

Here are the relevant functions from the Gist:

```
flatten <- function(indt, cols, drop = FALSE) {
  require(data.table)
  if (!is.data.table(indt)) indt <- as.data.table(indt)
  x <- unlist(indt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) max(lengths(x))), .SDcols = cols])
  nams <- paste(rep(cols, x), sequence(x), sep = "_")
  indt[, (nams) := unlist(lapply(.SD, transpose), recursive = FALSE), .SDcols = (cols)]
  if (isTRUE(drop)) indt[, (cols) := NULL]
  indt[]
}

flattenLong <- function(indt, cols) {
  ob <- setdiff(names(indt), cols)
  x <- flatten(indt, cols, TRUE)
  mv <- lapply(cols, function(y) grep(sprintf("^%s_", y), names(x)))
  setorderv(melt(x, measure.vars = mv, value.name = cols), ob)[]
}
```

Finally, here's the usage. Note that you can figure out the expected number of rows by taking the maximum length list item and multiplying it by the existing number of rows. In this case, 3 x 4 = 12 rows.

Here's `df_1`:

```
flattenLong(df_1, c("B", "C"))
#            A variable  B  C
#  1:  chicago        1 NA NA
#  2:  chicago        2 NA NA
#  3:  chicago        3 NA NA
#  4:   london        1  a  A
#  5:   london        2  b  B
#  6:   london        3  c  C
#  7: new york        1  f  F
#  8: new york        2 NA NA
#  9: new york        3 NA NA
# 10:   sydney        1  d  D
# 11:   sydney        2  e  E
# 12:   sydney        3 NA NA
```

Here's `df_2`:

```
flattenLong(df_2, c("B", "C"))
#            A variable  B  C
#  1:  chicago        1 NA  F
#  2:  chicago        2 NA  G
#  3:  chicago        3 NA NA
#  4:   london        1  a  A
#  5:   london        2  b  B
#  6:   london        3  c NA
#  7: new york        1  f  C
#  8: new york        2 NA  D
#  9: new york        3 NA  E
# 10:   sydney        1  d NA
# 11:   sydney        2  e NA
# 12:   sydney        3 NA NA
```

And, as a bonus, if you prefer a "wide" format, that's possible by using `flatten` directly (which is called by `flattenLong`, as you can see in the code for the functions).

```
flatten(df_1, c("B", "C"))
#           A     B     C B_1 B_2 B_3 C_1 C_2 C_3
# 1:   london a,b,c A,B,C   a   b   c   A   B   C
# 2:   sydney   d,e   D,E   d   e  NA   D   E  NA
# 3: new york     f     F   f  NA  NA   F  NA  NA
# 4:  chicago  NULL  NULL  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Hmm could be useful in splitstackshape imho.

Comment: @lukeA, thanks. That's the intention, if I can find the time to actually focus on integrating some of my bug fixes and so on.... :-)

Comment: Noone _finds_ time, you have to _take_ it. ;) jk. Great package, use it alot, thx for the effort.

Comment: this looks like a great package. But I am getting an error `Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'transpose' not found`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3570187, can you check that you are using the most recent version of "data.table"?

Comment: @user3570187, you should be using at least version 1.9.6 of "data.table", which can be installed with `install.packages("data.table")` and loaded with `library(data.table)`.

Comment: Awesome!! You made my life!!! Superb solution!! Many appreciation to your technical prowess!!